# How to change the opacity of the firefox bookmarks toolbar?

Tags: firefox, themes, toolbar, opacity

It appears that with my update to Firefox 44 a few days ago, the **bookmarks toolbar** has gained the same opacity as the URL toolbar (adding something like 50% of a gray tone).

That's ugly.

I have tried

- reinstalling the *Aurora Australis* theme already, to no avail.
- the "Open Menu" -> "Customize..." dialog, but I can't seem to find a knob to frob the bookmark toolbar opacity.

How can I get rid of the opacity so that the theme is completely visible? I'm willing to hand-tune any `userChrome.css` you name in the absence of an easier method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want more transparency to see the theme, try

```
#PersonalToolbar {opacity: 0.1 !important }
```

or

```
#PlacesToolbarItems { opacity: 0.1 !important;  }
```

If you're going the `userChrome.css` route, you need to exit Firefox and restart it. If you use the [Stylish extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/), you can preview and save and effect your changes without closing the browser.

Please note that I didn't experience this problem because I don't use transparency but there are some related bugs:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1246005
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1215567
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1214707

Comment: Tuning the `userChrome.css` as shown does not work; the opacity makes the text disappear. It seems my theme (Aurora Australis) suffers from the first bug. I'll accept, since I now know that it's not something I have messed with and should wait for the bug to be fixed in firefox (or the theme). Thanks!

Comment: Please see if this thread is helpful: [Translucent Colored Booksmarks bar and Tab on newest build](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2988851)

Answer (score 1):

```
#PersonalToolbar { 
    background-color: transparent !important; background-image: none !important; 
}
```

putting this in my userChrome did it. I am using the [Hacker (Animated)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hacker-animated) theme. Here are my userChrome contents:

```
#main-window[lwthemetextcolor="bright"] #navigator-toolbox > #nav-bar, 

#main-window[lwthemetextcolor="bright"] #navigator-toolbox > #PersonalToolbar {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  background-image: none !important;
}

#PersonalToolbar { background-color: transparent !important; background-image: none !important; }
```

I found the code from a [comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/7x59cd/comment/du5qd7u/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) on a Reddit thread. I just removed a few and added the last line in myself.

Here's the [link](https://www.userchrome.org/how-create-userchrome-css.html) to the instructions on how to create a userChrome and enable it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the background opacity, this is easily done using the [Classic Theme Restorer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/classicthemerestorer/) Addon:

- Navigate to the Addons Preferences *Toolbar (3)* page
- check all "remove background color" fields
- I also had to change the tab theme back to "Firefox default (curved tabs)" in the *Tabs (1)* page.